# Select fixed number of records/rows from growing table from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, query

*Background:* A SQL-Server database table is used to store weekly reports of some system memory usage, meaning that each week a new table row/record/line is inserted.

The question is how a fixed number (e.g. 5 records) of records can be queried, with the side-condition that those records are equally spaced within the time-range.

if this was the table

```
id | memory
----------- 
01  1231
02  1241
03  1260
04  1300
[.... other 92 rows ...]
97  2001
98  2002
99  2020
```

and with said 5 records I would like have a table as such

```
id | memory
----------- 
01  1231
25  1600
50  1800
75  1900
99  2020
```

since it would most represent the overall picture of the data.

Comment: You can get a rowcount of the target table and then divide that number by your "fixed number" and get your divisor.  Then select your target table where the ID value modulus your divisor is 0 (ID%@divisor).

Comment: @QueueMann Do you think that this would work in query?

Comment: you mean without having to query the rowcount ahead of time?

Comment: @QueueMann I mean that the result would be a sql query, implying I need not use any other artifice like a programming language python, java....

Comment: yes - you can do the entire thing using only SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant way to achieve this but it can be done by using the NTILE function inside a CTE.

```
WITH cte AS (

  SELECT NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY id asc) AS dist,
  memory
  FROM TABLE)

  SELECT TOP 1 id, memory FROM cte WHERE dist = 1

  UNION

   SELECT TOP 1 id, memory FROM cte WHERE dist = 2

  UNION

   SELECT TOP 1 id, memory FROM cte WHERE dist = 3

  UNION

   SELECT TOP 1 id, memory FROM cte WHERE dist = 4

  UNION

   SELECT TOP 1 id, memory FROM cte WHERE dist = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @row_count int;
declare @rows_returned int = 5;

select @row_count = count(*) from MyTable;
select * from MyTable where id%(@row_count/@rows_returned) = 0;
```